# Перевод из дюйм в см

Tags: c

Привет.

Задание. Перевести дюймы в см. Т.е. ввожу 2i, должно вывести 5.08 см.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x;
    char ch;
    ch = getchar();
    scanf("%d%c", &x, &ch);
    //ch = getchar();
    if (x == 2 && ch == 'i')
        printf("%lf cm\n", 2.54 * x);
    //2i = 5.08cm
}
```

В чем ошибка? Я может что-то не понимаю, проверка вроде правильно стоит.

Comment: Чуть уточню формулировку ответа @dzhioev.

Вы результатом getchar() затирали в переменной ch 'i', которое вводили в scanf().

Если бы ввели **2ii** то все бы сработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем вы вызываете getchar? Он ведь считывает первый символ из ввода, поэтому дальше вы получаете не то, что ожидали.

Comment: во-во, и это тоже

Comment: убрал функцию getchar().
Зачем я его использовал гыг) итак же было char ch))
спасибо за ответ)